# If conditions inside select query or If conditions inside code behind? What is performance wise good?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, datatable

I have a MYSQL table that store contacts values of employees(add_contact_details). This add_contact_details table contain 3 millions of records.
I am using this select query to get the records from contacts from that table.

```
SELECT 
head.`add_title` AS `title`,
head.`add_description` AS `descp`,
con.`con_name` AS `name`,
IF(
con.`con_status_show_email` = TRUE,
con.`con_email`,
NULL
) AS `email`
  FROM
`add_header` AS `head` 
INNER JOIN `add_contact_details` AS `con` 
ON head.`add_id` = con.`add_id_ref`;
```

So if con_status_show_email=true then email field will return email else the column will return NULL value. So I am getting that out put to datatable in webform and visible false or true the email label according to that.
So that is what I am doing now.

What if i do this?

```
SELECT 
head.`add_title` AS `title`,
head.`add_description` AS `descp`,
con.`con_name` AS `name`,
con.`con_status_show_email`,
con.`con_email`
from
`add_header` AS `head` 
INNER JOIN `add_contact_details` AS `con` ;
```

So in here it return additional columns to datatable. So in code behind I have to check if con_status_show_email contain null visible false the email label and if it true return the email in con_email column.

So both methods doing the same thing. diffrence is in the first method small if part works inside the DB and return few columns to datatable. 
In second method it just reutn query result to datatable and in code behind its doing some if part.
So what is best?
If I use "If" statements in select queries will it cause to performance issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance-wise, I would do the following:

1. get rid of that `if` function
2. return both the `con_status_show_email` and `con_email` columns and then decide at runtime on code behind whether to display the email field
3. Million records? You will definitely need server-side paging, so add some server-side paging rather than running a select-all query unless this is a query associated with reporting

#### Answer to comments

> What I did is just bind the datatable to gridview in aspx. And I
>   already enabled the paging in gridview. Is that ok? Or do I need to
>   control the number of records which is coming from the select query?
>   Does enabling the paging option will do the magic?

The GridView default paging function is not good enough for your case, you need custom paging by implementing a query that returns only the data that the cosuming code needs specified by the GridView's page size

> Why you saying that get rid of the If statement. Is Databases are inefficient regarding this?

Absolutely, if you are retrieving millions of records, the `if` function will be evaluate for each and every record in the `select` query...that is, it'll be evaluated a million times

Comment: Thank you for your answer Leo. Why you saying that get rid of the If statement. Is Databases are inefficient regarding this? What I did is just bind the datatable to gridview in aspx. And I already enabled the paging in gridview. Is that ok? Or  do I need to control the number of records which is coming from the select query? Does enabling the paging option will do the magic?